# How to get the amount of subfield nodes in a xml file

Tags: python-3.x, xml-parsing

I am trying to extract data from an xml file. I get the xml file by accessing a previously generated url to the api of the xml provider. Normally the datafields I need are only present once, but sometimes, the datafield node is present multiple times.

This is the code I use: (it's only a part of the code, so indenting might be a bit off)

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    with urlopen(str(row)) as response:
                    doc = ET.parse(response)  
                    root = doc.getroot()
                    namespaces = {  
                "zs": "http://www.loc.gov/zing/srw/",
                "": "http://www.loc.gov/MARC21/slim",
                    }
                datafield_nodes_path = "./zs:records/zs:record/zs:recordData/record/datafield"  # XPath
                datafield_attribute_filters = [ #which fields to extract
                {
                "tag": "100", #author
                "ind1": "1",
                "ind2": " ",
                }]      
                no_aut = True
                for datafield_node in root.iterfind(datafield_nodes_path, namespaces=namespaces):
                    if any(datafield_node.get(k) != v for attr_dict in datafield_attribute_filters for k,v in attr_dict.items()):
                        continue
                    
                    for subfield_node in datafield_node.iterfind("./subfield[@code='a']", namespaces=namespaces):
                        clean_aut.append(subfield_node.text) #this gets the author name
                        no_aut = False
                if no_aut: clean_aut.append(None)
```

This works fine for 80% of the URLs I access, but the remaining 20% are either broken or have multiple `subfield_nodes` for the `datafield_attribute_filter` I'm searching.

Here's an example URL of multiple occurrences: [example link](http://services.dnb.de/sru/dnb?version=1.1&operation=searchRetrieve&query=ISBN%3D9788393093243&recordSchema=MARC21-xml)

When this URL gets loaded into `urlopen` I get the Author nine times instead of once.
Is there a way to count the number of occurences and if the `datafield_node` is present more than once, to only take the first occuring `datafield_node`?
I have tried using `findall` from ET but got no usable results.

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is not how I wanted to solve it, this did the trick:

```
append_author=0
no_aut = True
   for datafield_node in root.iterfind(datafield_nodes_path, namespaces=namespaces):
   if any(datafield_node.get(k) != v for attr_dict in datafield_attribute_filters for k,v in attr_dict.items()):
                        continue
   if append_author ==0
       for subfield_node in datafield_node.iterfind("./subfield[@code='a']", namespaces=namespaces):
       clean_aut.append(subfield_node.text) #this gets the author name
       no_aut = False
       append_author+=1
```

as soon as the first field gets appended, the others get skipped